# Toggle from Left to Right issue

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I was trying to have a `navigate toggle list from left to right side`.If i click the button,the list should come as native android app in `css`,But the list should slide from left to right.

```
$(".logo").click(function()
                {
                    $(".sidebar_list").toggle('slide');
                });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMYW9/1/)

Example Image:

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BMYW9/2/  check this if it serves your requirement

Comment: @DipaliVasani : This works fine,But my actual output is not this one,Thanks Dipali :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my Expected answer..

Here is my code.

```
$(".logo").click(function()
                {
                    $(".sidebar_list").animate({
                    width: 'toggle'
                }, 100)
                });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMYW9/3/)